# Add external dependencies of external assemblies with Scrutor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, dependencies, scrutor

I wrote this extension method to scan assembly from another folder.

```cs
public static IImplementationTypeSelector FromExternalAssemblies(
    this IAssemblySelector selector, ConfigurationManager configurationManager)
{
    var virgilioMainFolder = configurationManager["ExternalFolder:Folder"];
    var assembliesToLoad = new List<string>();
    configurationManager.GetSection("ExternalFolder:AssembliesToLoad")
        .Bind(assembliesToLoad);
    var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    foreach (var pathAssembly in assembliesToLoad)
    {
        try
        {
            var fullPathAssembly = Path.Combine(virgilioMainFolder, pathAssembly);
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fullPathAssembly);

            assemblies.Add(assembly);

            //selector = selector.FromAssemblyDependencies(assembly);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    var assembliesArray = assemblies.ToArray<Assembly>();

    return selector.FromAssemblies(assembliesArray);
}
```

It works fine but it can't load the external dependencies of the external assembly loaded.

How can I load the external dependencies? Is it possible?

Comment: Avoid using `Assembly.LoadFile` and prefer `Assembly.Load`. [This article](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/assembly-loading-resolution-conflicts.html) describes why.

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies?view=net-8.0) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Steven I tried as you suggested but the assembly is in another folder so the system can't get the location of it.   "Could not load file or assembly [...] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Make sure the referenced assemblies are deployed with your application.